# I encountered an error when compiling sonic;

Tags: python, pip, sonic

```
Processing ./sonic_py_common-1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./sonic_platform_common-1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./swsssdk-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./asyncsnmp-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 316, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
    collected.requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 168, in _add_to_criteria
    candidates=build_iter_view(matches),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 164, in build_iter_view
    matches = list(matches)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 417, in <genexpr>
    and all(req.is_satisfied_by(c) for req in requirements[identifier])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 417, in <genexpr>
    and all(req.is_satisfied_by(c) for req in requirements[identifier])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/requirements.py", line 39, in is_satisfied_by
    return candidate == self.candidate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 172, in __eq__
    return links_equivalent(self._link, other._link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/models/link.py", line 288, in links_equivalent
    return _CleanResult.from_link(link1) == _CleanResult.from_link(link2)
AttributeError: type object '_CleanResult' has no attribute 'from_link'
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /python-wheels/ && pip install sonic_py_common-1.0-py3-none-any.whl sonic_platform_common-1.0-py3-none-any.whl swsssdk-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl asyncsnmp-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl' returned a non-zero code: 2
[  FAIL LOG END  ] [ target/docker-snmp-sv2.gz ]
slave.mk:542: recipe for target 'target/docker-snmp-sv2.gz' failed
make: *** [target/docker-snmp-sv2.gz] Error 1
```

This is an error about sonic when complining. What is the cause of this error and how to solve it. My previous compilations were successful;I don't know why this error occurs.